# Retrieve value of attribute using XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to retrieve the value of an attribute from an xmel file using XPath and I am not sure where I am going wrong..

This is the XML File

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
  <soapenv:Header>
    <common:TestInfo testID="PI1" />
  </soapenv:Header>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And this is the code I am using to get the value. Both of these return nothing..

```
XPathBuilder getTestID = new XPathBuilder("local-name(/*[local-name(.)='Envelope']/*[local-name(.)='Header']/*[local-name(.)='TestInfo'])");
XPathBuilder getTestID2 = new XPathBuilder("Envelope/Header/TestInfo/@testID");

Object doc2 = getTestID.evaluate(context, sourceXML);
Object doc3 = getTestID2.evaluate(context, sourceXML);
```

How can I retrieve the value of testID?

Comment: Which of the many `XPathBuilder` implementations are you using?

Comment: Please make sure to post *valid* XML, the `<soapenv:Envelope/> closing tag actually was another opening one.

Comment: Possibly off-topic, but as this concerns SOAP: if you're trying to implement your own SOAP service/request parser, please don't; you'll cut yourself on one of its many many sharp edges.

Answer (score 0):

The XML file you provided does not contain an `<Envelope>` element, so an expression that requires it will never match.

**Post-edit edit**

As can be seen from your XML snippet, the document uses a specific namespace for the elements you're trying to match. An XPath engine is namespace-aware, meaning you'll have to ask it exactly what you need. And, keep in mind that a namespace is defined by its uri, *not* by its abbreviation (so, `/namespace:element` doesn't do much unless you let the XPath engine know what the namespace `namespace` refers to).

Comment: I was just showing a cross section as an example. Need help with the XPath expression..

Comment: While that is understandable, please always provide enough data for anyone here to reproduce the problem, should they decide to try. Asking people to help based on half a problem doesn't work well :)

Answer (score 0):

However you're iterating within the java, your context node is probably not what you think, so remove the "." specifier in your `local-name(.)` like so:

`/*[local-name()='Header']/*[local-name()='TestInfo']/@testID` worked fine for me with your XML, although as akaIDIOT says, there isn't an `<Envelope>` tag to be seen.

Comment: I've added the Envelope tags to show that I do have them. The XPath string still isn't working with my code..

Comment: There's no difference between `local-name()` and `local-name(.)`.  The first one is just one character shorter.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care for the namespaces and use an XPath 2.0 compatible engine, use `*` for it.

```
//*:Header/*:TestInfo/@testID
```

will return the desired input.

It will probably be more elegant to register the needed namespaces (not covered here, depends on your XPath engine) and query using these:

```
//soapenv:Header/common:TestInfo/@testID
```

Comment: That's not valid XPath. You can't use `*` as a namespace prefix wildcard.

Comment: You're right, it isn't valid XPath 1.0, but [allowed in XPath 2.0](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/namespace-wildcards-in-xpath). I added this to my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your first XPath has an extra `local-name()` wrapped around the whole thing:

```
local-name(/*[local-name(.)='Envelope']/*[local-name(.)='Header']
                                                         /*[local-name(.)='TestInfo'])
```

The result of this XPath will either be the string value "TestInfo" if the `TestInfo` node is found, or a blank string if it is not.

If your XML is structured like you say it is, then this should work:

```
/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Header']/*[local-name()='TestInfo']/@testID
```

But preferably, you should be working with namespaces properly instead of (ab)using `local-name()`. I have a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14393528/1945651) that shows how to do this in Java.