# javax.xml, XPath is not extracted from XML with namespaces

Tags: java, xml, xpath

There is "original" XML

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header>
        <context xmlns="urn:zimbra">
            <session id="555">555</session>
            <change token="333"/>
        </context>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <AuthResponse xmlns="urn:zimbraAccount">
            <lifetime>172799999</lifetime>
            <session id="555">555</session>
            <skin>carbon</skin>
        </AuthResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The XML is parsed in this way

```
// javax.xml.parsers.*
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(pathToXml);
```

Then I'm trying to extract session id by XPath

```
// javax.xml.xpath.*;
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
// next xpath does not work with Java and online xpath tester
//XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/context/session/text()");
// this xpath works with online xpath tester but does not with in Java
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/*[name()='context']/*[name()='session']/text()");
String sessionId = (String)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

Tested here
http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/678ae9388e3ae2fc8406eb8cf14f3119

When the XML is simplified to this

```
<Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <Header>
        <context>
            <session id="555">555</session>
            <change token="333"/>
        </context>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <AuthResponse xmlns="urn:zimbraAccount">
            <lifetime>172799999</lifetime>
            <session id="555">555</session>
            <skin>carbon</skin>
        </AuthResponse>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

This XPath does its job

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/Envelope/Header/context/session/text()");
```

How to extract session id from "original" XML with Java?

UPDATE: JDK 1.6

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6392700/592746

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that you need to [correctly use namespaces and namespace prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392200/parsing-xml-that-has-different-namespaces-using-xpath-in-java/14393528#14393528):

First, make your `DocumentBuilderFactory` namespace aware by calling this before you use it:

```
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

Then do this to retrieve the value you want:

```
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        if (prefix.equals("soap")) {
            return "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope";
        }
        if (prefix.equals("zmb")) {
            return "urn:zimbra";
        }

        return XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
});

XPathExpression expr = 
       xpath.compile("/soap:Envelope/soap:Header/zmb:context/zmb:session");
String sessionId = (String)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
```

You may need to add a line to the beginning of your file to import the NamespaceContext class:

```
import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
```

http://ideone.com/X3iX5N

Comment: Hi JLRishe, unfortunately this does not work for me. BTW, I have to use JDK1.6.

Comment: `NamespaceContext` appears to be available starting with JDK1.5: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html

Comment: When I mentioned about JDK1.6 I implied that "switch" construction is not applicable for String object type. But that is trivial. "this does not work" - it means that when I replaced the switch with "if->return, if->return" the sessionId was empty after XPathExpression evaluation. And even when I tried to add "/text()" or "/@id" at the end of the XPath the sessionId was still empty.

Comment: Ok, after 20 minutes of frustration, I finally remembered that the `DocumentBuilderFactory` has the infuriating behavior of ignoring namespaces unless you tell it to pay attention to them. Please see my edited answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You can always do it by ignoring namespace, not the ideal method but works.

```
 "/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Header']/*[local-name()='context']/*[local-name()='session']/text()"
```

Comment: Thanks Sean F, your solution does work. I think two XML nodes with the same name on the same level but with different namespace is not good design, right?